# Как проверить тип полученного контента Aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Мне нужно чтобы пользователь отправил боту фотографию.
Вот кусок кода и функция которую я использую для получения и сохранения изображения.

```
from aiogram import types, Dispatcher
from create_app import dp, bot
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import State, StatesGroup
import os, sys, pathlib

class FSMRegister(StatesGroup):
    shop = State()
    name = State()
    position = State()
    photo = State()

...

async def reg_photo(message : types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['photo'] = message.photo[0].file_id
    file_info = await bot.get_file(message.photo[0].file_id)
    filename, file_extension = os.path.splitext(file_info.file_path)
    await message.photo[-1].download('uploads/image' + file_extension)
    async with state.proxy() as data:
         await message.reply(str(data))
    await state.finish()

def register_handlers_register( dp : Dispatcher ):
    ...
    dp.register_message_handler(reg_photo, content_types=['photo'], state=FSMRegister.photo)
```

Но если пользователь отправляет вместо фотографии другой тип файла или текст то функция не срабатывает.
Как мне сделать что-бы при возникновении такой ситуации бот в ответ отправлял сообщение о некорректности отправленных данных?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы обрабатывать все типы сообщений укажите `content_types=['any']`
Потом надо просто проверять есть ли фотография в сообщении

```
async def reg_photo(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    if message.photo:
        pass # Ваш код в случае если пользователь отправил фото
    else:
        await message.answer("Это не фото")
    
def register_handlers_register( dp : Dispatcher ):
    dp.register_message_handler(reg_photo, content_types=['any'], state=FSMRegister.photo)
```

Answer (score 0):

Может когда-то кому-то пригодится. Добавил проверку на тип сообщения и вызвал еще раз функцию reg_photo в register_handlers_register без указания типа контента:

```
async def reg_photo(message : types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    if message.content_type!='photo':
        await message.answer('Отправьте, пожалуйста, свою фотографию')
        return
    async with state.proxy() as data:
    ....

def register_handlers_register( dp : Dispatcher ):
....
    dp.register_message_handler(reg_photo, content_types=['photo'], state=FSMRegister.photo)
    dp.register_message_handler(reg_photo, state=FSMRegister.photo)
```